# file downloads successful but corrupt in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My File download is successful but when i download it the file/ image says (corrupted). Help. (My goal is to download from pgadmin and not folder)

View

```
<div class="row">
      <form role="form" method="post" action="<?php  echo site_url('website/web/uploads1')  ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">photo</label>
          <input type="file" class="form-control" id="pic" name="pic">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
```

Controller

```
public function uploads1(){
  $es_data = pg_escapte_bytea(file_get_contents($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name']));
  $man = pg_unescape_bytea($es_data);
  header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
  header('Content-Type: '. 'image/jpeg');
  header('Content-Length: '. '100000');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='. 'a.jpg');

  echo $man;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: sorry its not base64_encode it is pg_escape_bytea. I am trying to escape it.

Comment: edit your question.

Comment: open file in text editor, check top and bottom for errors.

Comment: Are you trying to upload file or download file? If your trying to upload file http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: even added blank space results in file corruption on download. So make sure the blank lines on your php file doesn't add into you data stream. I have to go with @Dagon's suggestion: open the downloaded file in a text editor: compare the original file to the downloaded one in the text editor. Any difference may give a bad result. Also, if  you have php script errors, they will get thrown inside the downloaded file.